# How to add top shadow on rectangle drawable

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-drawable

I have a rectangle drawable that needs to display a top shadow only, I can't use elevation because it will place shadow in all the component, instead I just need to place a drop shadow in top of this drawable

What I need

[image]

What I currently have

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/white" />
    <corners
        android:topLeftRadius="20dp"
        android:topRightRadius="20dp" />
</shape>
```

This draws the borders to the view, but there is no top shadow on it, instead is just a plain white image

Answer (score 0):

The most straight-forward way to solve this would be by creating a 9-patch image of a shadow, then aligning that to the top of the view, but this approach has some issues, like not being able to play with the corner radius value, resolution issues, etc.

Another option is to generate a blur image of your view (e.g., with Renderscript / ScriptIntrinsicBlur), then save that to a bitmap, and use that image as the shadow - altho this option is somewhat cumbersome and has costly performance.

Another option would be to use elevation normally, but then have this view aligned all the way to the bottom of the screen, or have another view with the same elevation value obscuring the shadow on the bottom.

I'm afraid there's no way to directly control how the elevation shadow is rendered besides this, and there's no way to access the Android SDK code that draws this directly.